# Is $\mathbb{E}\left[ (Y-X)^{2} \right]=0$ equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(Y=X)=1$?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I have a space definied as follows

$\mathcal{L}^{2}=\lbrace X: X-\text{real-valued random variable}, \mathbb{E}(X^{2})<\infty \rbrace$

My textbook later states that we don't differentiate between two random variables $X,Y$ which differ on a set of measure zero. This condition is written as $\mathbb{E}\left[ (Y-X)^{2}  \right]=0$. I see it better when I write $\mathbb{P}(Y=X)=1$. So, the question is: are those two equivalent? I guess they are; it makes sense to me intuituvely, but I have trouble explaining it formally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.  In one direction, if $X=Y$ except on a set of measure zero, then $(X-Y)^2=0$ almost everywhere, and thus integrates to zero.  In the other direction, if a non-negative integrable function has integral zero, it must be equal to zero almost everywhere.